# I can be "educational" (Depending on your opinion)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Happy Friday everybody! Here is a little "What am I" riddle for you to enjoy! Happy solving!

> Though I am only **three letters**, I can mean a lot.
>
> I can be "**educational**" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.
>
> Everyone needs a **little** of me.
>
> I can give you a glimpse of different **worlds**.
>
> Or I can simply be something that makes you feel **happy**.

HINT #1:

> One of the lines is a famous slogan (* cough * LINE 3)

HINT #2

> It could be a three letter abbreviation. ;)

Comment: Given the large numbers of valid but incorrect answers, I think this might be "Too Broad"

Comment: Crozier, could you please give some additional hints or information which would help to narrow down the solution? I agree with @ChrisCudmore that there are quite a variety of possible incorrect but valid answers given.

Comment: Take a look at the comment I put on Vivek Parekh's second answer. There is a major clue in there! I can add that clue to the top! @El-Guest

Comment: @Crozier, yes, adding visibility to that clue by adding it to the top would definitely help! Thanks!

Comment: Also, once you find the answer it will be quite obvious, as one of the lines is a major slogan for the answer if you were to Google it. I don't want to just give it away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> TLC?

Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.

> TLC can stand for the TV network "The Learning Channel" or for "tender loving care".

I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.

> TLC can stand for the TV network (*it used to be educational*) or for "tender loving care".

Everyone needs a little of me.

> Everyone needs a little TLC.

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> TLC is a network which has a whole bunch of wacky shows (I guess different worlds can refer to different walks of life).

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> Tender loving care certainly can do that.

Comment: Yes! You are correct, congratulations! Wacky TV shows is right, lol! :D

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Art?

Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.

> What is art (the classic artist's conundrum)?

I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.

> Art can indeed be educational. You can get degrees in various artistic studies. Or you can be abstract (I'm not saying it isn't educational, but it is more random).

Everyone needs a little of me.

> One of the basic human needs is creativity. If you don't have art, you're not really living. You're only not dying.

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> Authors create worlds in their writing, so do painters.

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> It can be pleasant just to stare at a painting.

Comment: Good try, but incorrect! :) @Joe-You-Know

Comment: Ahh I was just about to post this myself!! We're still on the same page, @Joe-You-Know

Answer (score 6):

Would you happen to be:

> Fun?

*Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.*

> Both children and adults all enjoy fun, and interestingly *fun* has 3 definitions.

*I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.*

> Fun can be used to increase retention of material in a learning environment; plus, fun is a *noun*, *adjective*, and a *verb*.

*Everyone needs a little of me.*

> Everyone does need a little fun in their lives. This can take on different meanings to different people. For example, fun to me is working on my car or reading a book; fun to you could be shooting guns and riding roller coasters.

*I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.*

> Everyone has fun using their imaginations at some point in life, this can allow you to not just see, but visit other worlds.

*Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.*

> Fun is typically associated with happiness.

Another guess (this is a long shot):

> H2O; though technically a number and two letters, it definitely meets all of the criteria.

New Guess:

> Would you happen to be ***see***?

Comment: Nice guess, but incorrect! :) @PerpetualJ

Comment: @Crozier I'm adding a secondary guess to my answer.

Comment: Making another attempt @Crozier.

Comment: Still incorrect, but good try!

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> The three Rs, reading, 'riting, and 'rithmetic?

Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.

> Those three letters represent the educational system fundamentals.

I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.

> They relate to education, or they can just relate to words.

Everyone needs a little of me.

> Everyone needs to know how to do at least a bit of any of them.

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> The world of a storybook, or the world of math, perhaps?

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> I personally enjoy math, others enjoy reading and writing too

Comment: Very good guess, but incorrect! :) @El-Guest

Comment: If I had another guess, would you want me to change my answer or add another one @Crozier?

Comment: You could add another, then you might get even more upvotes! :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Act?

Every point is self-explanatory, i guess

Comment: Incorrect, sorry! :) @VivekParekh

Comment: removed the edit and added a new answer

Comment: No, every point is not self-explanatory. Please could you edit your answer to explain it better?

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> WWW (World Wide Web)?

*Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.*

> www is quite big

*I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.*

> Depends on how a person uses it

Everyone needs a little of me.

> Everyone needs to access it

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> You can have a look at the different parts of the world

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> This is subjective

Comment: I wouldn't say it meets the *need* category. Still a good guess.

Comment: Still incorrect, but I like how your answer was an abbreviation, you are on the right track! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Mass?

Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.

> Mass contains 3 unique letters.

I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.

> I guess you could consider a church mass as educational.

Everyone needs a little of me.

> We all need mass to exist.

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> Gravitational lensing can allow you to see distant worlds.

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> Bach's Mass in B Minor Could make someone feel happy.

Comment: Good try, but incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

I thought of int., but that was too unpredictable. Also, everyone needs a little luv in their life, but somehow WWW was close, so that wasn't it. Maybe it isn't an abbreviation, after all, that wink was suspicious.

But after I saw it was the 151st most common acronym out of 12977 of them, i will guess:

> int.

Is it close? Far? 
 <strike>What's the perfect puzzle?</strike> 
Please give another hint if it's wrong.

Comment: Oops, wrong. Somebody got it! Wow, people are way .. super smart.

Comment: Good answer though! And excellent research on the acronym -- what does it stand for?

Comment: A lot. https://www.abbreviations.com/INT

Answer (score -2):

Are you?

> Sex

Though I am only three letters, I can mean a lot.

> Sex means a lot, especially in a relationship

I can be "educational" if I want or I can just mean a series of nouns and adjectives.

> We know there is "Sex Education", and it could be sex as noun (gender)

Everyone needs a little of me.

> I think it's part of our biology that we need it

I can give you a glimpse of different worlds.

> When we engage in intercourse, we share different thoughts and feelings with our partner

Or I can simply be something that makes you feel happy.

> In my opinion nobody get's sad during/after sex, unless you're forced.

Comment: No, incorrect sorry.

Comment: Not really appropriate for the site?