# Do you know, or don't you?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am formed of letters three,
>   Have a go - can you find me?
>
> When you give me legs,
>   I'll help you see the stars.
>   When you take me fishing,
>   I'll help you playing music.
>
> When I join a rock band,
>   I'm like a good hard puzzle.
>   When I'm making promotion,
>   I might join mafia gangs.

Comment: Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/69864/5373), although the solution is entirely different.

Comment: Is the sixth line supposed to be read as "I'll help you (while) playing music", or "I'll help you play music"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm gonna take a guess and say that you are

> Tri

Here comes the stretch:

I am formed of letters three,
Have a go - can you find me?

> Not only you are formed of three letters, you are also a form of the number three.

When you give me legs,
I'll help you see the stars.

> **Tri**pod is used as a leg for the telescope.

When you take me fishing,
I'll help you playing music.

> Angle can also mean fish hook. **Tri**angle is a musical instrument.

When I join a rock band,
I'm like a good hard puzzle.

> A hard puzzle can be **tri**cky. [CKY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKY_(band)) is an American rock band.

When I'm making promotion,
I might join mafia gangs.

> Making promotion = AD

and

> **Tri**ad is used to call the mobs from China, Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan.

Comment: This must surely be more or less it. I wonder (1) whether the intended answer is a homophone that's an actual word and (2) whether the title is a _Star Wars_ reference. (Even though IIRC the OP is slightly infamous on scifi.stackexchange.com for never having seen any of the _Star Wars_ movies.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have a doubt on (1), myself, because It doesn't fit in with how the other solutions to the clues are constructed but I can’t seem to find the one that does so I give up and go with (1).

Comment: Yes, this it it - well done! @Gareth The intended answer is what Kevorobin said, but the title is indeed a reference to the homophone which is an actual word. (Your parenthetical is also correct, but I've picked up a lot of Star Wars knowledge simply by osmosis on SFF.SE :-) )