# A Lot of Meaning in a Small Word

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Visit a jungle and I will disappear.
>
> One, two meanings I have,
>
> My second one can describe me.
>
> Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot
>
> Add some math and I may become two.
>
> I have one and so may you,
>
> A lot of care I require otherwise,
>
> Beasts may lurk.

So, tell me this **What am I**?

**Hint**

> This puzzle has **heavy** wordplay.

**Hint 2**

> Take some lines literally!

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69864/i-can-be-educational-depending-on-your-opinion) puzzle.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I was actually wondering the same thing as Cubemaster haha!

Comment: That puzzle actually stumped me for a while, but once I got the second infix I thought it was quite the tribute to you, @QuantumTwinkie!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is:

> Yard

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> There are no yards in the 'concrete' jungle

One, two meanings I have,

> Open/grassy area around a house.  Length measurement.

My second one can describe me.

> The measurements of a yard can be expressed in yards.

Though I only have a few letters I mean "a lot"

> A 'lot' here meaning a vacant exterior space, the same as a yard.

Add some math and I may become two.

> You can subdivide yards.

I have one and so may you,

> My home has a yard, yours may too

A lot of care I require other wise, Beasts may lurk.

> Overgrown yards can attract animals and pests

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Guvf vf nyzbfg pbeerpg nf V jnf tbvat sbe gur jbeq lneq, juvpu jbhyq uryc znxr frafr bs fbzr pyhrf, Terng wbo +! :Q

Comment: , very nice riddle

Comment: Also, @RhinoWalrus if you change Rot13(ybg gb lneq) I will accept in 24-30 hours :D

Answer (score 3):

are you a

> House/home?

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> There are no houses in the jungle

One, two meanings I have, My second one can describe me.

> Not quite sure, but some say that "the home is where the heart is" which is kind of a second meaning.

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> Only 4/5 letters, but a house plays a huge part in a person's life, and their emotions are tied to it.

Add some math and I may become two.

> No idea

I have one and so may you,

> Most people have a home

A lot of care I require other wise, Beasts may lurk.

> If you don't take care of your house, you might get mice or cockroaches, or other "beasts".

Comment: Close but no cigar +1

Answer (score 3):

Would it be

> heart?

line 1

> 'to lose heart' means to be discouraged

line 2

> 'heart' can mean a physical organ, or it has various metaphorical meanings.

line 3

> The physical organ definition literally defines the heart in the human body? Not sure.

line 4

> 'heart' is not a long word.

line 5

> 'h' is Planck's constant. Adding 'h' to heart gives another word?

line 6

> Probably talking about compassion.

line 7

> Be careful of heartless people!

line 8

> 'Beasts lurking in your heart' is a saying.

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct, but great try +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be

> ZOO

Here is my try

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> Obvious( when one visits a jungle - with animals, no need of a separate zoo to visit)

One, two meanings I have,

> Zoo has two meanings...

My second one can describe me.

> Second meaning of zoo is disorder.

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> Zoo has only 3 letters, but can mean a lot.

Add some math and I may become two.

> Zoo - in a way -  2 + 0 + 0  = 2, though stretched!

I have one and so may you,

> Not sure - on this part.

A lot of care I require other wise,

> A zoo requires a lot protection or else

Beasts may lurk.

> Wild animals can roam around.

Comment: Great guess, but not correct +1

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Log

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> You dont really find them in the jungle

One, two meanings I have,

> math, lumber, record

My second one can describe me.

> record

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> extensive records

Add some math and I may become two.

> Log(4)

I have one and so may you,

> some way to keep track

A lot of care I require other wise,

Beasts may lurk.

> temites

Comment: Great first answer, but unfortunately incorrect :) +1 P.S. Welcome to the site take a [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) here to earn a badge!

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Power

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> Humans don't really have any power in a jungle.

One, two meanings I have,

> Power as the ability to influence others, or act in a certain way; and power as in electrical power.

My second one can describe me.

> Symbol for electrical power is the uppercase letter P.

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> Power has only 5 letters.

Add some math and I may become two.

> We can calculate the power of a number. For example 2 is (1/2)th power of 4.

I have one and so may you,

> We can all have power. :)

A lot of care I require other wise,

Beasts may lurk.

> If you are not careful you can lose your power, and then depend from other people, or become vulnerable.. So, beasts would have a metaphorical meaning here.

Comment: Sorry, not correct, but great try! +1

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Son/Sun

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> The sun will typically disappear in a jungle

One, two meanings I have,

> Sun/Son

My second one can describe me.

> The second letter in Sun is U (you); or perhaps you are a son to your parents?

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> Son

Add some math and I may become two.

> s + 1 = t, u + 2 = w, n + 1 = o

I have one and so may you,

> Well, I have a son. Perhaps you do too???

A lot of care I require otherwise,
Beasts may lurk.

> I suppose this might reference the need to care for your child (son). you DID say heavy wordplay  :)

Comment: Another great, guess, I guess I have to add another hint to clarify what I mean +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Land

Visit a jungle and I will disappear.

> Not much free land or unoccupied space in a jungle

One, two meanings I have,

> Land such as homeland or land on the backyard (or land as a verb)

My second one can describe me.

> My Land or my country can describe me

Though I only have a few letters I mean a lot

> Land is precious for ancestral or other reasons

Add some math and I may become two.

> Land can be divided

I have one and so may you,

> Land can be bought

A lot of care I require other wise,

> Land requires tilling (farming)

Beasts may lurk.

> Wild animals may be living on your land

Comment: Great answer, but RhinoWalrus got it slightly before you +1 :)